# How to create custom access permissions for entity form

Tags: entities

I am using Entityforms on my site. I want to be able to create custom access permissions, which would prevent users of role 'member' from submitting more than 2 submissions. I am fine doing this programatically, but I haven't yet found a good way of doing this.

I tried using the `hook_entityform_access_alter`, but I dont see where its called. I tried printing some dpms and they never showed up anywhere:

```
/**
* Implements hook_entityform_access_alter().
*/
function wai_scholarship_access_entityform_access_alter(&$access, $op, $context) {
 dpm($access);
 dpm($op);
 dpm($context);
}
```

Comment: Can't you set these permissions in the Access settings tab in the Entityform edit UI? /admin/structure/entityform_types/manage/second_form

Comment: I don't think so. You can set access restrictions there per Role, not for the additional requirements I have, to only block after two submissions.... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons the dpm()'s in your hook are not showing is that this hook function is not being called when you access the form as an administrator (administrators bypass all access restrictions). I tested this for authenticated users, and it does work. The hook is called as expected. (To test it yourself be sure to allow devel permission to the authenticated user so that you can see the output of the dpm).  The hook is being called when a user accesses the form.

Comment: Perfect, that was it. I'm now able to use the account object attached to the $context variable to run a query for submissions with that uid.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do something like this

```
  $count = db_result(db_query("SELECT sum(data) FROM {webform_submitted_data} WHERE nid = %d AND cid = 7", $node->nid));

  // The submission limit is 125 - if it has been exceeded...
  if ($count >= 125) {
    // Uncheck all role access for this node. This disables access so users will see
    // this message when they navigate to the form: 'Registrations are no longer being accepted as this event is full. Thank you for your interest.'
    $node->webform['roles'] = array();

    // Save the node with all roles unchecked
    node_save($node);
  }
```

the code is for webform but you will get rough idea of how to approach it